# Placing stone over metal fireplace face. Is this possible?

Tags: tile, fireplace, stone

let me start by saying I have seen mixed answers all over the web (and from professionals whom I have spoke to). At this point I wanted to hear thoughts from folks online.

As seen in my picture I am looking to tile the remaining black metal fireplace face with the same stone seen surrounding it. I have checked the installation instructions and the metal can be covered with a non combustible material. It is also worth noting the fireplace is gas, the metal is pretty solid (doesn’t expand when I push it) and even after running the fireplace for 2-3 hours it doesn’t get to hot to the touch. (But definitely heats up)

My question is: Is it possible to apply a tile or stone to this black metal fireplace using modern technology? If so how? I have been told the following solutions “could” work:

1.) use latapoxy 310 to set the stone directly on the metal face

2.) use latapoxy or a high tempature adhesive to glue concrete board to the metal face and tile as needed.

3.) screw the cement board directly to the metal box and tile as needed (could also glue and screw using high tempature adhesive)

4.) use some special mortar which handles high temps tires

5.) there were other options using lathes and what not but outside my realm of understanding :)

I would love to hear opinions on this, if anyone has done this? If it’s possible?

Thanks so much guys!
[image: Fireplace]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manufacturer of the fireplace is okay with it, so you definitely can. I have done it many times and I found it the best option is to use cement board and then the appropriate application method for the finishing material. I've always used high temperature morter of various kinds and never had an issue. The key to remember is, accessibility to service the fireplace. Any openable panels must remain that way. Avoid man made stone that has epoxy in it as it tends to discolour. Many fireplaces I have installed are actually unfinished everywhere except the glass and require a stone finishing right up to it.

From the Safety data sheet 
 [image]

Comment: How would you recommend the best way to anchor the cement board to the metal face? Would screws / epoxy be my best bet?

Comment: I've always screwed them in, making sure they aren't going to hit anything inside. And I avoid putting screws around the serviceable areas. I learned that after having to do a service on one and ended up bleeding all over the place.

Comment: +1 for recommending high temp mortar. Without it, the rock could sag when heated.

Comment: Awesome thank you:) for a high temp mortar could I use any fireplace mortar? For example https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rutland-10-lbs-Dry-Mix-211-Refractory-Mortar-Tub-211/300981819 I know that’s typically for stacking bricks (I think) but would that work?

Comment: In my experience there seem to be two main types. Softer combustion chamber stuff and really hard stuff. I'm used to seeing calcium aluminate /sand mixtures for the harder variety. Up in the answer I added an image discloseing the composition for the fireplace morter from your link. Mullite and kaolin are components of porcelain. Dextrin is a bonding agent. Calcium aluminate cement is the high temperature component. It's going to be very hard stuff. You should be good with that one.